# Adding 0.39 Double variable in Java

Tags: java, double

Need few suggestions on a strange behavior in adding a double with ONLY 0.39 (strange number). First snippet has proper example with 0.38 and the second with 0.39

```
// code snippet 1 : Adding xxxx.38 to xxxx.00

double b =1031.38;
double a =1587.00;
System.out.println ("using double     "+(a+b));

BigDecimal premium = BigDecimal.valueOf(a);
BigDecimal netToCompany = BigDecimal.valueOf(b);
double result =Double.parseDouble(premium.add(netToCompany).toString());
System.out.println("using BigDecimal "+result);

// correct Output xxxx.38 + xxxx.00 = xxxx.38

using double     2618.38
using BigDecimal 2618.38

***** ------------------------------ ******

// code snippet 2 : Adding xxxx.39 to xxxx.00

double b =1031.39;
double a =1587.00;
System.out.println("using double     "+(a+b));

BigDecimal premium = BigDecimal.valueOf(a);
BigDecimal netToCompany = BigDecimal.valueOf(b);
double result =   Double.parseDouble(premium.add(netToCompany).toString());

// wrong Output xxxx.39 + xxxx.00 = xxxx.3900000000003

using double  2618.3900000000003
using BigDecimal 2618.39
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `BigDecimal`, you want to use the version that takes a `String`. If you use `double`, then you have **already** lost precision.

```
BigDecimal premium = new BigDecimal("1031.38");
BigDecimal netToCompany = new BigDecimal("1587.00");
```

Which outputs (as expected)

```
2618.38
```

**and** for `2618.39`

```
BigDecimal premium = new BigDecimal("1031.39");
BigDecimal netToCompany = new BigDecimal("1587.00");
System.out.println(premium.add(netToCompany));
```

**but**, if you need to use `double`, you *might* choose to use formatted output (which will round for you) like

```
double[] premiums = { 1031.38, 1031.39 };
double netToCompany = 1587.0;
for (double premium : premiums) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f%n", premium + netToCompany);
}
```

Comment: Thanks and i am aware of formatting but i should not as per needm The question is for only 0.39 why are we getting  2618.3900000000003. The long 000s after decimal. Doesn't happen for any otjer numbers. Will do format if i have no choice as suggested. Thx

Comment: @N.Murali [smbc - `0.1 + 0.2`](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2999)